# Android REST AsyncTask

Tags: android, rest, android-asynctask

Is there an Android REST framework that has AsyncTask rolled into it? It seems like this should be demanded by everyone, or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you probably describe more specifically what you are missing in the current implementation?

Comment: REST is more of an abstract idea than a defined API. There are different data transport formats (XML, JSON, ...), different requirements for the data objects / hierarchies in your code, REST APIs with different usage styles and so on. It is close to impossible to pack all that into a single framework that works for everyone. You either need to restrict it to certain types or it would be extremely complex to use. That big master framework also exists: It is the programming language where you can plug frameworks together that tackle specific parts like http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: That's actually what I am looking for, something like that. Threading off JSON parsing seems to be less annoying than threading both HTTP requests and JSON parsing. I find the Google I/O video to be extremely vague, and I don't understand why that's being shuffled around instead of a comprehensive framework. I've tried RESTlet and Spring for Android--it's sad that these developers can write these huge amounts of poorly documented code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution in Android that can be easely used for REST implementation and it's `IntentService`. You can check youtube for "Google I/O 2010 - Android REST client applications". You will find all best practives for REST in Android there.